# stop for loop in java

Tags: java, loops, mathematical-optimization

I have written code that computes the simple steepest descent algorithm, and there is an iteration of a for loop.

When the values of x1,x2 is the same as the minimizer, it should stop looping. But in my code it doesn't, instead it prints again and again the minimizer value.

Here is my code:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < MAX ; i++) {
    // ∇ƒ(x) =
    //     | 2(x1 - a) - c(x2 - b) |
    //     | 2(x2 - b) - c(x1 - a) |
    //
    // Apply x to ∇ƒ(x)
    double d1f1 = 2 * (x1 - a) - c * (x2 - b);
    double d1f2 = 2 * (x2 - b) - c * (x1 - a);

    // ∇²ƒ(x) =
    //     | 2    -c |
    //     | -c   2  |
    double d2f1 =  2.0;
    double d2f2 = -c;

    //we reach to the minimizer 
    if (d1f1 == 0 && d1f2 == 0)
    { 
        break;
    }

    // α = |d1f1 d1f2| * | d2f1 d2f2 | * | d1f1 | 
    //                   | d2f2 d2f1 |   | d1f2 |
    alpha = (d1f1 * d1f1 + d1f2 * d1f2) /
        (d1f1 * (d1f1 * d2f1 + d1f2 * d2f2) +
         d1f2 * (d1f1 * d2f2 + d1f2 * d2f1));

    // x1 = |x1| - α * | d1f1 |
    // x2 = |x2| - α * | d1f2 |
    x1 = x1 - alpha * d1f1;
    x2 = x2 - alpha * d1f2;

    // Debug
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.printf("alpha  = %.2f\n", alpha);
    System.out.printf("x1     = %.2f\n", x1);
    System.out.printf("x2     = %.2f\n", x2);
}
```

and the result:

```
a  = 5.00
x1 = 1.00
x2 = 4.00

alpha  = 0.28
x1     = 4.11
x2     = 1.11

alpha  = 2.47
x1     = 4.96
x2     = 2.02

alpha  = 0.28
x1     = 4.99
x2     = 1.99

alpha  = 2.47
x1     = 5.00
x2     = 2.00

alpha  = 0.28
x1     = 5.00
x2     = 2.00

alpha  = 2.47
x1     = 5.00
x2     = 2.00

alpha  = 0.28
x1     = 5.00
x2     = 2.00

alpha  = 2.47
x1     = 5.00
x2     = 2.00

alpha  = 0.28
x1     = 5.00
x2     = 2.00

alpha  = 2.47
x1     = 5.00
x2     = 2.00

alpha  = 0.28
x1     = 5.00
x2     = 2.00

alpha  = 2.47
x1     = 5.00
x2     = 2.00

alpha  = 0.28
x1     = 5.00
x2     = 2.00

alpha  = 2.47
x1     = 5.00
x2     = 2.00

alpha  = 0.28
x1     = 5.00
x2     = 2.00

alpha  = 2.17
x1     = 5.00
x2     = 2.00

alpha  = 0.28
x1     = 5.00
x2     = 2.00

alpha  = 2.50
x1     = 5.00
x2     = 2.00
final result
x1     = 5.00
x2     = 2.00
```

Comment: Try adding `System.out.printf("d1f1     = %.2f\n", d1f1);` and `System.out.printf("d1f2     = %.2f\n", d1f2);` right before your `if` statement to see what values are being checked.

Comment: thank u , it give me -0 :( , why 0-0 =0 why it is minus !

Comment: i write this but it still iteration , if (d1f1 == 0 && d1f2 == 0 || d1f1 == -0 && d1f2 == 0 || d1f1 == 0 && d1f2 == -0 || d1f1 == -0 && d1f2 == -0  )
            { 
                break;
            } 
@MichelfrancisBustillos

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it's the real problem, but you should never check exact equality using doubles. That is because operations like multiplication or division using double are most likely not exact. Better choose some small number `epsilon>0` and check if the absolute value of your double is smaller than epsilon.

Comment: In such situations I like to link [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: sorry , i'm not perfect in java programming .. but could u tell me which type i must use here.

Comment: It's also a double value than you can choose 'small enough'. You have to decide how precise the result should be.

Comment: @user2199395 if this answer helped you, don't forget to accept it